# To pass data in List<dynamic> in flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, postman

i'm trying to print body from the API to see if i'm getting my data but unfortunately nothing return if i try to print below List

Here is my code to get data from the server/api

```
  Future<List<Permission>> getPermissionData() async {
    String ruhusa = 'permission';
    Response resp = await http.get(mainUrl + ruhusa,
        headers: setHeader(accessKey.accessKey));

    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(resp.body);
      // print("data zangy ${resp.body}");

      List<Permission> permissions =
          body.map((dynamic item) => Permission.fromJson(item)).toList();

      return permissions;
    } else {
      throw "Can't get permission.";
    }
  }
```

anyone who can help please!!

Comment: var body = jsonDecode(resp.body);

print(body);

first try this then tell me the output

Comment: it return body of the post from the API and that's what exactly I want, but with List<dynamic> nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

Set the type of item that map is returning to **"Permission"**

```
  List<Permission> permissions =
          body.map<Permission>((dynamic item) => Permission.fromJson(item)).toList();
```

The error might be because you're trying to assign a dynamic list that map is returning to the list of permission.

Comment: The exactly problem of why I was unable to pass the data was in my Permission model, in requesting permission user was not supposed to fill all the field so other fields where null. so I changed all null field from String datatype  to dynamic and it worked